Ktor error: Neither port nor sslPort specified
So, I've read numerous answers on how to resolve this error, but it doesn't seem to apply to my situation.
This is a ktor application, built with maven.
I'm getting the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Neither port nor sslPort specified. Use command line options -port/-sslPort or configure connectors in application.conf
First of all, my application runs fine in IntelliJ Ultimate, but fails when I try to run the fatjar on the commandline like this: java -jar target/myApp-jar-with-dependencies.jar
The crux of the matter seems to be that I'm having my configuration in an application.yaml file.
I've included this dependency:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-config-yaml-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>

My application structure looks like this:

When I create an application.conf in the same folder it works fine, which indicates that it just does not expect a yaml configuration file, even when I've included the ktor yaml dependency.
Lastly, my maven build segment looks like this:
 <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin_version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>17</jvmTarget>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>kotlinx-serialization</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-serialization</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin_version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Any help would be appreciated.

Can you share the code of the main function?

@AlekseiTirman That would be fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

I suggest double-checking that you don't have the application.conf file. Also, you can step into the line (https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/861c112defc0b99732bb1475091c4ed47a01966d/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/jvmAndNix/src/io/ktor/server/config/ConfigLoaders.kt#L33) with a debugger to see which config is actually being loaded.

Sorry, this line - https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/861c112defc0b99732bb1475091c4ed47a01966d/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/jvmAndNix/src/io/ktor/server/config/ConfigLoaders.kt#L43

@AlekseiTirman At least when running in Intellij It doesn't reach that line; CONFIG_PATH is empty, hence there are no iterations of that loop. There's also no application.conf in my project, though I do see a custom.config.conf, which is none of my doing, when I open the jar (however, this defines port, so I'm guessing it's not used based on the error message).

Ktor uses the ServiceLoader to load all the available config loaders and then tries to load the default configuration with each. The HoconConfigLoader is defined in the ktor-server-core-jvm module, and the YamlConfigLoader is defined in the ktor-server-config-yaml-jvm module. As far as I understand, the assembly Maven plugin takes the META-INF/services/io.ktor.server.config.ConfigLoader file of the first package containing that file and packages it in the result JAR.
Since the ktor-server-core-jvm module goes first in the dependencies block in the pom.xml, the plugin packages only a definition of the HoconConfigLoader and ignores the one for YAML. As a result, the application only tries to load the application.conf file, which doesn't exist.
To solve the problem, switch the order of the dependencies in the pom.xml file:
<dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- To be able to use yaml as server configuration -->
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-config-yaml-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Ktor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-core-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- ... -->
<dependencies>


This worked! And thanks for the explanation as well. I actually tried moving the dependency further up, but I didn't think to move it above the server-code dependency. I don't know if you work with ktor on an official capacity, but I've seen your answers on several other posts as well, so thanks for helping so many people around here.

I'm seeing exactly the same issue and this suggestion didn't resolve it unfortunately.

To Add to my comment above, I'm seeing these entries in the jar file:
io/ktor/server/config/HoconConfigLoader.class,
META-INF/services/io.ktor.server.config.ConfigLoader,
io/ktor/server/config/yaml/YamlConfigLoader.class.

I am facing the same issue and the solution didn't work even after clean install. @MaksymBykovskyy have you found a solution?

I figured out that the newly generated project also has a wrong dependency. Use ktor-server-config-yaml-jvm instead of ktor-server-config-yaml @MaksymBykovskyy mb that may help you

Aleksei is indeed correct about the META-INF/services/io.ktor.server.config.ConfigLoader file. I came up with a an alternative solution which, in my opinion, is less fragile as it doesn't depend on the order of dependencies in the POM. I configured the Maven assembly plugin to merge any files under META-INF/services/ with the same filename. Here's one way to do that using an inlineDescriptor (another approach would be to use a separate assembly.xml file):
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <inlineDescriptors>
      <inlineDescriptor>
        <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
        <formats>
          <format>jar</format>
        </formats>
        <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
        <dependencySets>
          <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependencySet>
        </dependencySets>
        <containerDescriptorHandlers>
          <containerDescriptorHandler>
            <handlerName>metaInf-services</handlerName>
          </containerDescriptorHandler>
        </containerDescriptorHandlers>
      </inlineDescriptor>
    </inlineDescriptors>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>assemble-all</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

This is basically a copy of the predefined jar-with-dependencies assembly descriptor with an added containerDescriptorHandler section which instructs the assembly plugin to merge files under META-INF/services/.
